# What is this plague-like thing in my lucky bamboo? Is it damaging?

Tags: diagnosis, lucky-bamboo

Can someone please help me identify what this orange larvae - like thing is in this lucky bamboo? I was cleaning the yellow leaves and notices it. This plant has over 2 years now.

[image: example one]
[image: example 2]
Thanks!

Comment: Can you take one off and see if its actually alive or whether its inert? What's  the plant growing in - water or soil?

Comment: It looks a bit like the roots you find on the stalk of pineapples when you peel off the lower leaves. Was this UNDER a leaf before?

Comment: They are aerial roots. Do you mist the plant frequently?

Comment: Thank you for all the responses! The plant is growing in water, and I do mist it somewhat frequently (usually two times a week, i live in a 35C weather with not so much moist). I basically water it when I see it's dry.

The plant has never been under any other plant. I has been close to mint and pepper plants but Im not sure it's possible that it got it from them

So apparently it's not really something to be worried about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are definitely it’s own aerial roots. You can cut this stem and replant it, so you’ll have more fluffy plant bouquet.

Comment: Thank you! I'll mark this as accepted because other people indicated this as well and it sounds reasonable :). I'll try planting it too!